# Do we want a weekly topic challenge?

Tags: discussion

***Putting this idea on pause.***  I think it's a nice idea, but there's not enough enthusiasm for it to make it worthwhile.

Also, I think the idea needs re-inventing for this site.  What I think would instead work:

- picking a topic I personally wish to study and designating it a *study topic*,
- encouraging others to join in if they want, (but if they don't want to join in, I can just study it by myself),
- maintaining a meta post for the study topic, with links to each question that has arisen,
- ignoring the "weekly" restriction (e.g. in case I end up busy on something else), and just run it until...

  1. I feel satisfied with my level of knowledge on the topic, and
  2. everybody has stopped participating.

---

***Weekly topic challenge.*** There's a curious initiative on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240634/351283) by Jon Ericson ♦, the weekly topic challenge, to encourage investigation on specific topics within a specific week.  This might be a good way for fighting against a post-Ramadan lull.

1. *Step 1*: Ask for topic ideas.

   Post topic ideas as answers to this question, where they can be upvoted based on popularity.  Basically, we suggest some Islam-related topic we, as a community, would be interested in learning more about in particular.
2. *Step 2*: Post a challenge.

   Whichever topic is voted to the top, we create a separate meta thread to pose it as a challenge for the week.  Those participating in the challenge ask or answer questions about the topic.
3. *Step 3*: <strike>Profit!!!!</strike> Tally the results.

   We tabulate the associated questions and answers generated that week.  We pat ourselves on the back.
4. *Step 4*: Repeat until you run out of topics.

---

Whether or not this is a good initiative depends on the community getting behind it.

Perhaps someone here is skilled in answering questions on certain topics (and wishes there was more questions about it). I think this would make a good topic suggestion.

*Update*: [status-deferred](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred).

Comment: I have deleted my former post to split it into two new posts. For the sake of a clearer voting!

Comment: @Medi1Saif: Honestly, I don't see enough motivation for this.  I could push for it, but I think it'd be better to try again later when the community is more enthused.

Answer (score 2):

### Proposed topic: Surah al-Kahf

My prayer app reminds me every Friday that I should read Surah al-Kahf ([quran.com](https://quran.com/18); [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Kahf)), the 18-th chapter of the Qur'an.  It seems this surah has some extra significance I'm largely unaware of.

Questions about Qur'an verses are about as on-topic as it gets for the site, and often can be answered authoritatively.

---

There's currently a [surat-al-kahf](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surat-al-kahf) tag with 6 questions, which does not seem as much as it deserves.

1. [Why did Al-Khidr kill a boy who had not committed any sin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2464/17163)
2. [What happend to the second garden of the disbeliever?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31388/17163)
3. [Does the sun set in a murky pool in Qur'an 18:86?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36653/17163)
4. [Why does Moses seem to take Khizr slaying a boy lightly?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33209/17163)
5. [Surah Al-Kahf 18:9-22: What is this story about youths in a cave?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30052/17163)
6. [What is the reason of this differences in the three expressions in Surat Al-Kahf 79 - 82?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1100/17163)

Answer (score 2):

### Proposed topic: The marriage contract.

I know only little about the [Islamic marriage contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_marriage_contract) (Katb el-Kitab).  I'd be interested in:

- what does a typical one contain (does this vary from sect to sect?),
- what extras can the couple add in, and what do they ordinarily add in,
- which extras are considered legitimate (I hear "no polygyny" can be a condition, but that it's invalid because it's the legal right of the husband in the Qur'an)
- There's currently three "citations needed" on Wikipedia; fact-checking them, and identifying authoritative references can make decent questions.

Current questions:

- [Is the Islamic marriage contract (Katb el-Kitab) considered a Prenup type contract in the Islamic world?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12313/17163)
- [Adding conditions to the nikah contract after nikah has taken place](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25749/17163)
- [What kind of condition are invalid in a nikah contract? Can not having intercourse be a condition?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37541/17163)

Answer (score 2):

### Proposed topic: Takfir

> In Islamic law, [takfir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takfir) or takfeer refers to the practice of excommunication, one Muslim declaring another Muslim as kafir (non-believer). The act which precipitates takfir is termed the mukaffir. An ill-founded takfir accusation is a major forbidden act.

I can think of a few questions here:

- Under what conditions can a Muslim declare someone a non-believer?
- Is it ever necessary to declare someone a non-believer, or is it better to simply never do this?
- After being declared a non-believer by a Muslim, how can one reassure themselves that they are indeed a Muslim?
- Is it haram to declare groups of Muslims non-believers?
- What are the consequences of incorrectly declaring someone a non-believer?

Answer (score 1):

## Proposed topic: The Maliki madhhab

For some reason, of the four madhhabs, we are the furthest behind on asking Maliki-specific questions [maliki](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maliki) (6 Q's).

Compared to:

- [hanafi](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hanafi) (68 Q's),
- [hanbali](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hanbali) (6) plus [salafi](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salafi) (15),
- [shafii](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shafii) (17).

[Medi1Saif](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/35340/17163) gave a handy guide to the differences between madhhabs.  Wikipedia also describes [Notable differences from other schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maliki#Notable_differences_from_other_schools).  There's a bunch of Maliki fatawa at [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/category/maliki).

---

Also, the site's 3-rd highest reputation user [مجاهد](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/9/%D9%85%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF) wrote [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/212/17163) (in 2013):

> I am familiar with the Maliki, Hanafi, and Shafi schools. I am currently studying in depth the Maliki school.

But this user stopped participating around mid-2015 (I'm not aware of the circumstances).  However, maybe... maybe the site is more attractive than before, and asking Maliki-specific questions may be a further attraction.

Comment: Nice idea, but most of those questions have been asked while he was still active.

Answer (score 0):

**Topics in an Alphabetical order**

Why couldn't we just chose topics in an alphabetical order?
1st week: a topic starting with "A" such as adab, ablution,
2nd week: a topic starting with "B" such as bidah or belief.
etc.
of course there would be some characters which would have less topics than others!

So maybe we can make it pseudo-alphabetic, what I mean not strictly taking the next character but maybe one of the 3 next characters in the alphabet for the next topic, like if the last topic was "fiqh" we can go ahead either with "history" or "guardian* or "imaam"

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for it!
Even if I'm afraid that I won't be able to contribute that much because of a "*somewhat known issue*"!

**Suggestion: Zakat**

I'd suggest "zakat" as a first topic, because somehow we have lots of questions on the site about this topic, but even if it is one of the 5 pillars the answer rate for this topic -at least this is my feeling- seems rather weak or low.

I must admit, that one of my first thoughts when proposing zakat was also to make a check how many of the given questions are basically "unanswered" duplicates!

I also would like to learn more about this topic and would have at least one question in mind!